# getUserMedia Detection JS

Tags: javascript, detection, getusermedia

I am currently using a getUserMedia function in order to have the user's voice recorded. This same algorithm is used in cwilso's JavaScript tuner: https://github.com/cwilso/PitchDetect

I want to be able to know when the microphone is ready for recording, so the user does not assume the program is broken when the mic is not loaded.

In the GitHub the mic loads immediately, but if I run it on mobile it takes some time before starting.

I know this is a very peculiar problem, but any help, even pointing me in a direction, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance! Please comment if I was not clear anywhere.

Comment: @t.Niese Thank you! If you want, you can make this an answer with syntax and I'll give you the reputation.

Comment: @t.niese getUserMedia is **NOT** deprecated. As the MDN article you mention points out, it's just moved to [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) and now returns a promise instead of taking callbacks.

Comment: [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), returns a Promise, that will either be rejected or resolve, so you can show a loading indicator until the Promise is either rejected or resolved, on success you can check the status of the stream for more details. (Deleted the old comment that was about the old deprecated function, thanks to @jib for the comment)